# An App with Identifier "<APP_ID>" cannot be submitted

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am trying to create an App ID:

[image: exampleAppID]

I have not enabled anything besides the default "In app purchases" and "Game Center" services in the app services section.

One thing that is odd is that if I change the App-ID to

> "com.roymunsonstudios.Copypasta-Keyboardwhythisnotwork"

it will actually work, is this maybe because my app ID has already been taken?.

Here is my Xcode target's settings page incase that is helpful:

[image]

Also this is the first step I am taking in preparing my app for release so I have not done anything else up to this point besides coding.